# time_slider using geemap and leefmap

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap, leafmap

I am new to using geemap, I am trying to create a time slider to show a group of TIFF files I created using Google Earth Engine. I am using colab and following this tutorial:
https://leafmap.org/notebooks/79_timeseries/

```
drive_folder_path ='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hYs1abaPl2La58CagSh9pbaxirc_kcU4/view?usp=sharing'
leafmap.download_file(drive_folder_path)
# Create a Map instance
m = geemap.Map()
# Add time slider with Google Drive folder URL
m.add_time_slider( 'geemap',
                  time_interval=0.5, 
                  position='bottomright', 
                  band=[1, 2, 3], 
                  zoom_to_layer=True)

# Display the map
m
```

But it gives me this error:
TypeError: The ee_object must be an ee.Image or ee.ImageCollection

The link already contains a folder named geemap and contains a TIFF file  with names DDMMYYYY

Answer (score 0):

The notebook you are following is using `leafmap.Map` not `geemap.Map`.

You are getting the error because `geemap.Map` expects either `ee.Image` or `ee.ImageCollection`:

`geemap.Map`:

```py
def add_time_slider(
    ee_object: Any,
    vis_params: Any = {},
    region: Any | None = None,
    layer_name: str = "Time series",
    labels: Any | None = None,
    time_interval: int = 1,
    position: str = "bottomright",
    slider_length: str = "150px",
    date_format: str = "YYYY-MM-dd",
    opacity: float = 1,
    **kwargs: Any
) -> None
```

> Adds a time slider to the map.
>
> Args:
> ee_object (ee.Image | ee.ImageCollection): The Image or ImageCollection to visualize.
> vis_params (dict, optional): Visualization parameters to use for visualizing image. Defaults to {}.
> region (ee.Geometry | ee.FeatureCollection): The region to visualize.
> layer_name (str, optional): The layer name to be used. Defaults to "Time series".
> labels (list, optional): The list of labels to be used for the time series. Defaults to None.
> time_interval (int, optional): Time interval in seconds. Defaults to 1.
> position (str, optional): Position to place the time slider, can be any of ['topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright']. Defaults to "bottomright".
> slider_length (str, optional): Length of the time slider. Defaults to "150px".
> date_format (str, optional): The date format to use. Defaults to 'YYYY-MM-dd'.
> opacity (float, optional): The opacity of layers. Defaults to 1.0.
>
> Raises:
> TypeError: If the ee_object is not ee.Image | ee.ImageCollection.

`leafmap.Map`:

```py
def add_time_slider(
    layers: Any = {},
    labels: Any | None = None,
    time_interval: int = 1,
    position: str = "bottomright",
    slider_length: str = "150px",
    zoom_to_layer: bool = False,
    **kwargs: Any
) -> None
```

> Adds a time slider to the map.
>
> Args:
> layers (dict, optional): The dictionary containing a set of XYZ tile layers.
> labels (list, optional): The list of labels to be used for the time series. Defaults to None.
> time_interval (int, optional): Time interval in seconds. Defaults to 1.
> position (str, optional): Position to place the time slider, can be any of ['topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright']. Defaults to "bottomright".
> slider_length (str, optional): Length of the time slider. Defaults to "150px".
> zoom_to_layer (bool, optional): Whether to zoom to the extent of the selected layer. Defaults to False.

Comment: you are totally right!! seems i was looking in the both libraries!! thank you. 
Now I have the problem that i get the map with a zoom to the correct location and get the  slider which is moves as the tiff images are changed .. but the actually the images are not loaded ! 
This is the updated code: 
`images=leafmap.download_folder("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ucb7s3Z4obEKnBnF4k2GPexvVsMlL43-?usp=drive_link") 
m = leafmap.Map()
m.add_time_slider(
    images,
    time_interval=0.5,
    position='bottomright',
    band=[1, 2, 3],
    zoom_to_layer=True
    )
m`

Comment: i already printed the images contects and get this: 
['/content/sentinel/01032019.tif',
 '/content/sentinel/01042019.tif',
 '/content/sentinel/01052019.tif']